# Can't set styles from js

Tags: javascript, stylesheet

I don't know why but this js script don't work for me:

```
document.getElementById('logo').style.width="300px";
```

That what I have included in header:

```
<link media="screen" href="/styles/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/libs.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

That is block I'm trying to set style for:

```
<a href="/index.php"><div id="logo">Some text</div></a>
```

Comment: How does it *not work*? Errors? No effect? Unintended effect?

Comment: FWIW, the syntax is correct. If you run `document.getElementById('hlogo').style.width="300px";` on this page in your console you'll see the SO logo width changed.

Comment: You're including jQuery, so why not use it? `$('#logo').css('width', '300px')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap it in something that instantiates it.

```
window.onload=function(){
document.getElementById('logo').style.width="300px";
};
```

Or in jQuery:

```
$(function(){
$('#logo').css( "width", "300" );
});
```